# Signing .apk causes app to freeze upon launch

Tags: android, build, configuration, apk, signing

I'm extremely confused as to why this could be happening. If I run the app with my debug configuration, it runs fine. If I run the app with the production configuration, that too runs fine. I thought it could be proguard getting in the way of things, so I turned proguard on + off for both my debug and production configurations, but that too didn't affect the app running perfectly.

It seems, that after I sign my .apk with the signing key that I'm using for the Google Play store, the app *launches* fine, but it'll get stuck on the splash screen and never do anything after that?

The extremely confusing thing is that it's strictly the act of signing my .apk file with the key causes my build to "freeze" on the splash screen. I'm not even getting any ANR error -- the app launches and never proceeds to execute any code after launch. In fact, after trying so many combinations of things, it seems that there's an extremely high correlation between signing the app and seeing it freeze. If I roll back several commits, the app can build + sign + run without issue as well.

Does anyone have any thoughts on why this could be happening?

Comment: The thing is that building my app with minifyEnabled set to either true or false on either flavor doesn't affect whether the app runs perfectly or not. Even when I manually build and sign the apk from within the terminal, the only time this is appearing is when the app is signed.

Comment: did you find an answer for this? I'm facing the same issue, very confusing